# Does click lib provide a way to print the builtin help message?

Tags: python, python-click

I am using the `click` lib.

In my code , sometimes I want to print help msg ,
But the only way I know is :

```
python xxx --help
```

But I want to print the help msg **in my code** using a certain function , for example:

```
click.print_help_msg()
```

Is there a function like this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Command's [get_help](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.Command.get_help) method

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--name', help='The person to greet.')
def hello(name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME."""
    click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

def print_help_msg(command):
    with click.Context(command) as ctx:
        click.echo(command.get_help(ctx))

>> print_help_msg(hello)
```

Comment: Sadly that's not working for my case I always get `AttributeError: 'name' object has no attribute 'allow_extra_args'`

Comment: if you're using nested groups and end up with "Usage:  [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]..." (ie. the root name is missing), then calling `with click.Context(command, info_name='mycli') as ctx:` will populate the name properly.

Comment: And if you want to print the help of a `@click.group` you can use your annotated group method instead of `command`.

Answer (score 22):

In click 5.x you can now use the `get_current_context()` method:

```
def print_help():
    ctx = click.get_current_context()
    click.echo(ctx.get_help())
    ctx.exit()
```

And if you're interested in just printing an error message and exiting, try:

```
def exit_with_msg():
    ctx = click.get_current_context()
    ctx.fail("Something unexpected happened")
```

Comment: Now with click 7.x, `ctx.exit()` gives an `AttributeError` as `exit()` has been removed. Exiting is implicit with Context unless it's utilized in a callback function (e.g. printing out your cli version via `MyCli.__version__`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `click.echo` something like this :

```
click.echo('FooBar')
```

`echo` also supports color codes and filtering based on type such as :

```
click.echo('FooBar', err=True)
```

You can refer to the [documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/utils/#printing-to-stdout) for more understanding.

Comment: I want the output of click.echo to be the same as the output of "python xxx --help" , is there any solution?

Answer (score -2):

I modified the sample on click's documentation and came up with this, I haven't used it before though, or tested the below code.

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--help')
def help():
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo(get_help_message())

def get_help_message():
    return "I AM A HELP MESSAGE!"
```

Would something like this not work?

Comment: I want the output of click.echo to be the same as the output of "python xxx --help" , is there any solution?