# How to access the main Context object of a Python Click application

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Consider the following minimal [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com) script `mytool.py`:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--name', help='The person to greet.')
def hello(name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME."""
    click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

How can I access the `Context` object Click generates for this script when I call it with

```
python mytool.py
```

In particular access to the the `info_name` attribute is important (so that, when I programmatically want to display the help message, the script name `mytool.py` is populated.(*)

---

(*) I know that I can generate a *new* Context object via `click.Context(hello)` but this context does *not* contain by itself the `info_name` property. Of course I can figure out the script name manually, but Click certainly creates a default context with the script name and I believe that one would be the best to access. (See also [Does click lib provide a way to print the builtin help message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140639/does-click-lib-provide-a-way-to-print-the-builtin-help-message))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/complex/

Add `@click.pass_context` as the final decorator and it becomes the first parameter in your function.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I was after. Thanks.